# Flutter Light / Dark Mode Event / Notification

Tags: flutter

I can easily detect light / dark mode in Flutter using below code

```
var isDark = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
```

However, for the sake of performance, I only want to run above code once during app initialization and later hook up events / notifications to change the value of isDark whenever user changes to light / dark mode.

I think it should be possible because Flutter changes the theme to light / dark automatically whenever I change to light / dark mode while the app is still running / in the background. I just can't find the code to do so for my own piece of logic.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve something like this I've used the package [dynamic_theme](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_theme). You have a link in the README to a Medium article which explains how to implement it.